# Display Scientific Notation for certain Columns only, Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to display results from a pandas dataframe, that contains small numbers.

```
dict1 = {
    'Name':['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
    'R1 (V)':[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4],
    'R2 (mV)':[1.1e-3,2.2e-3,3.3e-3,4.4e-3],
    'R3 (uV)':[1.1e-6,2.2e-6,3.3e-6,4.4e-6],
    'R4 (nV)':[1.1e-9,2.2e-9,3.3e-3,4.4e-9],
    'R5 (pV)':[1.1e-12,2.2e-12,3.3e-12,4.4e-12]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
```

[Output Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDVU1.png)

In my example here I want to change R3 to scientific notation (1.1e-6, 2.2e-6, ...) without changing how the other columns are displayed

Answer (score 3):

try to edit the format of your DataFrame like this:

```
df.style.format({'R3 (uV)': "{:.2E}"})
```

this will output the DataFrame with R3 in the scientific notation, but if you try to display the DataFrame again you will have to repeat this procedure because the format is not permanent

Comment: This does change the 'R3 (uV)' column but it also changes the format of the other columns

Comment: you can use this to define the format of each column

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the values to strings and apply the wanted notation.

```
df['R3 (uV)'] = df['R3 (uV)'].apply(lambda val: '%.2E' % val)
```

Comment: doing this you will loose your data transforming it into str. Use `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler` instead